# DataGridView DataError on Bound DataTable

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

So I have a `DataGridView` that has it `DataSource` property set to a `DataTable`.

The Table has three rows, the first two are read only, but the third is a Custom defined List Object, `DataViewList`. Everything displaying great and the first two columns are ReadOnly as they should be. The problem is in the Third Column.

The `DataViewList` implements the `IList<T>` interface. The only thing special about it is that the `ToString` method returns a comma separated list so that the `DataGridView` can Display that column.

The problem is that when the User makes changes to the third column, before I can catch the `CellEndEdit` Event, the `DataGridView` throws a `DataError` Event. I have tried to implement conversion on my Custom List but the `DataGridView` still throws an error, `` "Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'DataViewList`1" ``.

```
_data = new DataTable();
DataColumn column = _data.Columns.Add(FIRST, typeof(Element));
column.ReadOnly = true;
column = _data.Columns.Add(SECOND, typeof(Element));
column.ReadOnly = true;
column =_data.Columns.Add(RESULT, typeof(DataViewList<Element>));
dataGridView.DataSource = _data;
```

I know that because the `DataGridView` displays everything in TextBoxes that I will need to write code to process the user input, but I cannot find where to catch the input before the `DataGridView` fires the `DataError` Event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle [DataGridView.CellParsing Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellparsing(v=vs.110).aspx)

> If the standard conversion does not meet your needs, handle the `CellParsing` event to provide custom value conversion to the required type.
>
> When you convert the value yourself, replace the initial, formatted value of the `ConvertEventArgs.Value` property with the converted value in the type specified by the cell `ValueType` property. To indicate that no further parsing is necessary, set the `DataGridViewCellParsingEventArgs.ParsingApplied` property to `true`.